# Bash+cron: Redirecting, and restoring, stdout and stderr produces permission denied

Tags: bash, cron, stdout, stderr

I've got a script that calls out to a bunch of commands, some of which are noisy to stdout, some to stderr, some to both.  I intend the script to be run by cron, so I don't want it to be noisy and mail me every day -- only in error conditions.  So I do:

```
be_quiet() {
  # save stderr in FD 3
  exec 3>&2 

  exec &> /dev/null
}

die() {
  # restore stderr
  exec 2>&3

  echo $* > /dev/stderr
  exit 1
}
```

Then, i.e.

```
be_quiet
mkdir -p $CLIENT_ROOT || die "Could not create client root."
cd $CLIENT_ROOT || die "Could not cd to client root."
```

The intent being that I get specific and meaningful-to-me messages if there is an error, and nothing otherwise.  But what I'm seeing now is just

```
line 48: /dev/stderr: Permission denied
```

When run from the command line, this works.  When run via cron, it gives the permission denied message.  I'm unclear why.

Comment: Is `exec 3>&2` correct? stderr is `2` usually.

Comment: This means that you don't have write permissions on /dev/stderr. Do your cron jobs run under the same user and group id as your interactive shell? Do you automatically switch to a specific group in your .profile, perhaps tty?

Comment: > Is exec 3>&2 correct?

Yes.  As I said, this works when run interactively.

Try this script:

    echo "Visible 1" >> /dev/stderr
    exec 3>&2
    exec &> /dev/null
    echo "Invisible" >> /dev/stderr
    exec 2>&3
    echo "Visible 2" >> /dev/stderr

Again, this works interactively but fails via cron.

> Do your cron jobs run under the same user and group id as your interactive shell? 

Yes.

> Do you automatically switch to a specific group in your .profile

No.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
exec 2>&3
```

do

```
exec 3>&-
```

Comment: What does that do? Can you include the full example with stdout/stderr?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just redirect stdout in the cronjob to /dev/null? Don't use the be_quiet function, and change die to:

```
die() {
    echo "$*" >&2
}
```

Then, in your cronjob:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh >/dev/null
```

You should only get mail from cron when your script outputs something using the die function.

Comment: > Why not just redirect stdout ...

Because some of the commands that I run are noisy to stdout, and some to stderr (and some both).  As I said in the very first sentence of my question.

Comment: I must have misunderstood, you said you only want to be mailed for error conditions so I assumed you didn't want to see anything at all from stdout and everything from stderr.

Answer (score 0):

Many years later I've come across the perfect tool to solve the actual problem described in the first sentence: [chronic](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/moreutils/chronic.1.en.html), which:

> runs a command, and arranges for its standard out and standard error to only be displayed if the command fails (exits nonzero or crashes). If the command succeeds, any extraneous output will be hidden.

This is what I wanted!